# Getting error while translating the dictionary of text

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to convert student biography which is in the form of key value pair where key is Student role no. and value is the text.

Text is written in various languages - english , chinese etc.

I need to normalise the text and convert it into english language. .

I tried packages like TextBlob, goslate, googletrans but they all throw some error after converting 10-15 biographies.

**Error is** :

```
    HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

**Code**

```
for key, value in self.dict1.items():
#             print("initial value\n ", self.cm_dict[key])
            if value =='' or value is None:
                value='Unknown'
            else:
                print("*"*20)
                print("\n key :" , key)

                gs = goslate.Goslate()
                txt = gs.translate(value, 'en')
                print("\n Sentence before correction :\n ", value)
                value = txt
                print("\n Sentence after correction :\n ", value)
```

Comment: What's the full error message? 503 usually means a problem on the other end, not in your code.

Comment: This is the error I am getting while using goslate```

    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable```